# Regular Expression (preg_match_all)

Tags: php, preg-match, whitespace, preg-match-all

This is my code:

```
    <?php
    $matchWith = "http://videosite.com/ID123";
    preg_match_all('/\S\/videosite\.com\/(\w+)\S/i', $matchWith, $matches);  
    foreach($matches[1] as $value)
    {  
            print '<a href="http://videosite.com/'.$value.'">
    Hyperlink
    </a>';        

    }  
    ?>
```

It's not working.
I want to exclude every match that has a whitespace before or after the Link (with the ID).
I used `\S` for this.

For example if:

```
$matchWith = " http://videosite.com/ID123 ";
```

it should not display anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing starting delimiter and an escape:

```
preg_match_all('/\S\/videosite\.com\/(\w+)\S/i', $matchWith, $matches);  
                ^  ^
```

Comment: now I don't get a blank page anymore, but it still displays the link if there is a whitespace before or after the link like `$matchWith = " http://videosite.com/ID123 ";`

Answer (score 0):

You are misplacing the leading slash in the regex.
Try to use the following:

```
preg_match_all('/\Svideosite\.com\/(\w+)\S/i', $matchWith, $matches);
```

Comment: ok, now I don't get a blank page anymore, but if there is a whitespace it still displays the link. For example if `$matchWith = " http://videosite.com/ID123 ";` then it sould not display the link because this has a whitespace before or after the link. Thanks

Comment: So you have to embed http:// in your regex, or use a second regex after the first pass.